# Different React Component Syntax

Tags: reactjs, redux

currently learning React, and I have started with a boilerplate. They use this syntax:

```
export const Header = () => (
    ...
)

export default Header
```

Would the above code be equivalent to:

```
export default React.createClass({
    ...
})
```

or

```
export const CompName = React.createClass({
    ...
})
```

Please explain, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That is an example of the new(ish) [stateless functional component syntax](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions). It is a more concise way of having a component which is simply a single function that returns JSX based on props. [Here](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d#.vupczagkx) is a medium post with some more background.

Comment: I prefer to use these in most cases since they are simple. Some of the downsides to them however are: no react lifecycle methods (ie no componentDidMount, or etc); This means no shouldComponentUpdate method, which means you can't take advantage of certain performance optimizations  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html#avoiding-reconciling-the-dom .. that being said, I've found that most of my components are children of Redux container components, which DO (automatically) leverage shouldComponentUpdate, so it's not a big deal for me.